# Visa for connecting flight in Dubai? Need to recheck luggage

Tags: transit-visas, dubai

I have a Philippine passport and valid residence permit in Iceland. I'm flying from the Philippines to Iceland, via Dubai and Sweden. My layover at Dubai is 4.5 hours and the travel agent says I'll need to collect and recheck my luggage.

Do I need to pass through immigration in Dubai to get my luggage? Will I need a transit visa?